# BookSim2.0 Install

Tags: networking, system-installation, software-installation

what does this paragraph mean "The simulator files should now be in the booksim2.0/trunk/src/ directory. The simulator itself is written in C++ and has been specifically tested with the GNU G++ compiler (version ≥ 3). The front end of the simulator uses LEX and YACC generated parser to process the simulator configuration file; however, unless you plan on making changes to the front end parser, LEX and YACC are not needed. The Makefile should be edited so that the first few lines reflect the correct paths to the tools for your particular system. The default Makefile should work on the Stanford Leland machines. Type make to build the simulator" ?

Comment: Which part are you confused about? And what does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: I was trying to install Booksim simulator on ubuntu which requires LEX and YACC parser.  I installed LEX and YACC, the path in the Makefile is also edited. But when i run the example file by giving ./booksim torus88, it showed command not found.